# Python Binance detect hedge mode active or not

Tags: python, binance

I use the library [python-binance](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

When I connect my binance client, if I try to make a SHORT order, If Hedge mode is not active ([more about Hedge mode activation](https://www.binance.com/en/support/articles/360041819691-How-to-Enable-Hedge-Mode)) I got the following error :

```
binance.exceptions.BinanceAPIException: APIError(code=-4061): Order's position side does not match user's setting.
```

The code :

```
from binance.client import Client

client = Client(
    api_key,
    api_secret,
    )

# Here : I want to get if client accoutn has hedge mode enable or not like : 

# hedge_mode = client.get_hedge_mode_active() <--- This method does not exists on library



order = client.futures_create_order(
    symbol = "XRPUSDT",
    side = SIDE_BUY,
    positionSide = "SHORT",
    type = ORDER_TYPE_MARKET,
    quantity = 500,
    )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`positionSide` is for Hedge mode, specifically. Activating it allows you to hold both LONG and SHORT positions for the same symbol.

So, if you want the one-way mode (not the hedge mode) then you just need:

```
response = client.futures_create_order(
    timeInForce="GTC",
    symbol="BTCUSDT",
    side="BUY",
    type="LIMIT",
    quantity=1,
    price=1.00
)
```

To check if hedge mode is activated or not, just use:

```
client.futures_get_position_mode() #This in python-binance
```

Response:

```
{
    "dualSidePosition": true // "true": Hedge Mode mode; "false": One-way Mode
}
```

Docs from binance API:

https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/futures/en/#get-current-position-mode-user_data

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer but I already got the way to pass SHORT or LONG positions. I want to know before making an order, if the account has hedge mode activate. It's because some people will give me their API credentials and I need to check this before.

Comment: See my edit ther's a function in python binance for that

Comment: Thank you so much ! This new feature (v0.7.9) was not present in my 0.7.5 version.

Answer (score -2):

You can use this:

```
data = client.futures_get_position_mode()
print("Position mode: Hedge Mode" if data['dualSidePosition'] == True else "Position mode: OneWay Mode")
```

Comment: This answer have no added value than the accepted one.